How to reset all installation with jupyter and python different versions?
There has a been an issue with the python installation. I cannot run commands anymore on Mac unless I do python3 -m command.
I also have installed with brew python@3.11 and python@3.12, but I haven't found a way to run the jupyter notebook command, though it is installed (as I installed it with pip3), doing upgrades and all.
It seems that I should better reset all configurations from python. I removed the usr/local/lib opt and bin python named files and if I run with anaconda it seems that the jupyter notebook opens, but it doesn't run the cells
Could you please unlock this situation ?
So for more information I tried as well brew reinstall brew link brew unlink
Here is the error message on the jupyter lab or on the jupyter notebook

[I 2024-04-17 21:04:15.446 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restarting kernel (5/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.19/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.19/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in 
from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/init.py", line 7, in 
from .connect import *  # noqa: F403
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 12, in 
import jupyter_client
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_client/init.py", line 3, in 
from .asynchronous import AsyncKernelClient
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_client/asynchronous/init.py", line 1, in 
from .client import AsyncKernelClient  # noqa
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_client/asynchronous/client.py", line 8, in 
import zmq.asyncio
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/init.py", line 52, in 
from zmq import backend
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/init.py", line 30, in 
raise original_error from None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/init.py", line 25, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 31, in select_backend
mod = import_module(name)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.19/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/init.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/init.py", line 6, in 
from . import _zmq
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.py", line 14, in 
raise ImportError("zmq Cython backend has not been compiled") from None
ImportError: zmq Cython backend has not been compiled
[W 2024-04-17 21:04:18.472 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 2024-04-17 21:04:18.472 ServerApp] Kernel 37259402-9bfc-432c-af8a-5482035517b9 died, removing from map.


I actually rebooted the computer and it worked
